# binary tree to file with overloaded ostream and two classes

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, binary-tree, fstream

I would like to save my binary tree to txt file. Here's what I have

```
qt.h
#ifndef QT_H_INCLUDED
#define QT_H_INCLUDED

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Node{
    T data;
    Node<T> *left;
    Node<T> *right;
public:
    Node(T d) : data(d), left(nullptr), right(nullptr){}
    void print(){
        cout << data << endl;}
    T getData()const {
        return data;
    }
    void setData(const T &value){
        data = value;
    }
    template<typename X> friend class Tree;
    template<T> friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, Node &n);
};

template<typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, Node<T> &n){
    os << n->data;
    return os;
}
#endif // QT_H_INCLUDED
```

then tree.h

```
#ifndef TREE_H_INCLUDED
#define TREE_H_INCLUDED

#include "qt.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Tree{
    Node<T> *root;
    void insertIntoTree(T &d, Node<T> *&r);
    void printTree(Node<T> *r);
    void deleteTree(Node<T> *&r);
    Node<T>* findInTree(T &d, Node<T> *r, Node<T> *&parent);
    void deleteLeaf(Node<T> *p, Node<T> *q);
    void deleteInBranch(Node<T> *p, Node<T> *g);
    void zapisDoSouboru(Node<T> *r);
public:
    Tree() : root(nullptr){}
    ~Tree(){
        clean();
    }
    bool find(T d){
        Node<T> *dummy=nullptr;
        return findInTree(d, root, dummy);
    };
    void clean(){
        deleteTree(root);}
    void insert(T d){
        insertIntoTree(d, root);}
    void print(){
        printTree(root);
    }
    bool deleteNode(T d);
    void zapis(){
         zapisDoSouboru(root);
    }
}


template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::zapisDoSouboru(Node<T> *r){
    fstream f;
    f.open("mytext.txt", ios_base::app);
    if(r){
    f << r;
    }
    f.close();
    zapisDoSouboru(r->left);
    zapisDoSouboru(r->right);
}
```

the idea was to overload operator<< for Node and then use recursion in zapisDoSouboru and save it Node by Node. Unfortunately it does not work.
Does anybody know, where the problem is?
Thank you for helping

EDIT
in

```
class Tree{
 void zapis(ostream& f, Node<T> *r);
public:
 void zapisDoSouboru(){
    fstream f;
    f.open("mytext.txt", ios_base::app);
    zapis(f, root);
    f.close();
   }
}

template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::zapis(ostream& f,Node<T> *r){
    if(r){
    zapis(f, r->left);
    f << r;
    zapis(f, r->right);
    }
}
```

I changed the whole recursion, but now it looks like it works, but it doesnt write anything in the file. Isnt the reference to f wrong? The file opens and close, zapis() goes through all nodes.

Comment: Please refer to [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
It's impossible to help when you don't specify exactly what does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In the function zapisDoSouboru you need to check if the child nodes are nullptr otherwise it will segfault whenever it reaches the leaf nodes.

Here is the modified version:
template

```
void Tree<T>::zapisDoSouboru(Node<T> *r){
    fstream f;
    f.open("mytext.txt", ios_base::app);
    if(r){
    f << r;
    }
    f.close();

    if(nullptr != r->left) {
        zapisDoSouboru(r->left);
    }
    if(nullptr != r->right) {
        zapisDoSouboru(r->right);
    }
}
﻿
```

Also the operator you have defined for node it is not being picked up by the compiler.
This is the piece of code of your operator:

```
template<typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, Node<T> &n){
    os << n->data;
    return os;
}
```

The variable `n` it is passed by reference and you are accessing it with `->` which expects a pointer. The reason why the code compiles is because when you call `f << r` you actually call the operator with a `Node<T>*` so the compiler does not use the template function which expects a `Node<T>&`. Which means the template function is never instantiated.

I think there is not much need for having the operator overload in this case. You can just simply call `r->getData()`

Also general things i noticed while looking at the code:

- I would try to use unique_ptr
- I would try to avoid using friend classes
- I would refactor the code to not open and close the file at every recursive call

Let me know if you need any clarifications

Comment: right now I cannot avoid friend classes nor recursive call, it's school task, but I will keep it in my mind. I went through it again, the mistake in overloading the operator<< is clear to me now. With the recursive call in zapisDoSouboru, I wrote it another way